# How to start an Objective-C program in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

What is the command-line utility in Xcode to start an Objective-C program?

Comment: Do you mean, how can you compile an application from the command line using Xcode, or how do you start an application from within Xcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for [Terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Terminal) app: `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal`

Comment: It's in Applications/Utilities